# Why am i getting "system.formatexception" error

Tags: c#

I am getting the error "system.formatexception" when i am trying to run the following code. Can anyone explain me why. I am new to C#. Thank you.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n,m,j;
        n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        m = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


        long[] jars= new long[n];
        long sum=0;
        int a,b,k;

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        jars[i]=0;

        j = 0;
        while(j<m){

            a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            k = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            for(int i=a-1;i<=b-1;i++){
                jars[i]+=k;
            }
        j++;
        }

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        sum=sum+jars[i];

        Console.WriteLine(sum/n);

    }
```

Comment: In which line does the error occur? What is your input?

Comment: you'll get an indexOutOfBounds Exception at `jars[i]+=k` if you input "wrong" numbers and i do not getting an error if i give everything a 2. maybe you've hit some alphabetical chars ;)

Comment: @webber m passing the 5 and 3 as n and m and m getting a dialogue box like "unhandled exception of type System.FormatException"

Comment: You get a `FormatException` if `Convert.ToInt32` gets an invalid string as input. _Valid_ means: optional sign followed by a sequence of digits (0 through 9). You can use `int.TryParse` instead which returns whether or not tit could be parsed successfully.

Comment: @tim i am only passing 5 and 3 as input and yet i am getting the error?

Comment: @sebastian i didn't go that far yet :(

Comment: What happens if you try to step through the code line by line? In which line is the exception thrown?

Comment: @mario i just stepped into and my code was working fine. I am getting error only when i am debugging :(

Comment: @Tim Thank You. I guess i figured out where i was wrong. I was trying to read 2 integers from a single string. I divided the string into tokens to read them as two different strings. :)